# Python list remove append

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a file I am putting into a list and I am wanting to take some things out of it, and append to another list ( I have no problem with that), the problem I run into is removing the things out of the first list. below is what I have tried but it only removes every other from the original list.

```
list:
bob     g1  3110
bob     g2  244
bob     g3  -433
greg    fun112  10595
greg    fun113  -1203
greg    fun114  -3049.999
greg    fun115  3808
greg    fun116  320
greg    got112  -600
greg    got113  5958
greg    got114  1249


file1 = open('test','rb').read().splitlines()
file1=sorted(file1)
test_group = ['fun','got']
test= []

for product in file1:
    spt = product.split(",")
    for line in spt:
        if line[:3] in test_group:
            x = test.append(product)
            y = file1.remove(product)
```

the test [ ] list is fine all of the items I want in there go with no problem, but when I review file1 it only takes out every other one of 'fun' and 'got' lines

why is this only taking out every other one, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Don't try to modify a list you're iterating over! That's not going to work!

If you make a copy of the list, then it should work:

```
for product in file1[:]:
    spt = product.split(",")
    for line in spt:
        if line[:3] in test_group:
            x = test.append(product)
            y = file1.remove(product)
```

Comment: `append()` and `remove()` return `None`, so storing their values in `x` & `y` doesn't makes any sense.

Comment: that worked great, could you please explain what was causing the error, trying to learn from my many mistakes :)

Comment: consider [this example](http://pastebin.com/TsKv1YwC) - here while iterating over the list each item that is seen is printed and then removed. That means that now the next item in the list will be in it's pace, and as the index counter is incremented it is skipped in the next iteration (try to find out what remains in the list in the example :) ). This can lead to very nasty and hard to find errors, so it's best not to do it (it also says so in the [official python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements)

Answer (score 3):

You don't want to be manipulating an object you're currently iterating over (if you try this with a dictionary for instance, you'll actually get an exception).

Also, since `list.append` adn `list.remove` are in-place, it always returns `None` - so there's no point assigning the result to anything.

I'd do it something like the following:

```
with open('test') as fin:
    test = []
    other = []
    rows = (line.split() for line in fin)
    for name, group, value in rows:
        if group[:3] in ('fun', 'got'):
             add = test.append
        else: 
             add = other.append
        add([name, group, value])
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be because of the negative integers, it could be reading those as ones to skip over? have you tested that?